# White space render in html - Drupal 7?

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

When I used a module i have some problems. Some white space appeared

```
$content='';
$vocab = vuagame_getVocByName("the_loai_game");
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocab->vid);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $content.="<div class='contentBox'>";
    $content.="<div class='contentBoxHeader'>";
    $content.="<a href='/category/".$term->tid."'>".$term->name."</a>";
    $content.="</div>";
    $content.="<table class='gameTable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>";
    $content.= views_embed_view('home', 'page', $term->tid);
    $content.="</table>";
    $content.="<div class='seemorelink'><a href='/category/".$term->tid."'>Xem thêm</a></div>";
    $content.="</div><br/>";
}
return $content;
```

and here's the result with inspect element :

```
<div class="contentBox"><div class="contentBoxHeader"><a href="/category/23">18+</a></div>  
"

   "
<table class="gameTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"><tbody><tr>
```

Does anyone can find out my trouble? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

first, br tag is not a standard now.
debug it like this,

1)try the html without the loop first. or break the loop after its first cycle.
if white space still exits,
replace a href tag with

```
 "<a href='lorum.html'>ispum </a>"
```

and see if its gone.. there might be a chance of irregular tag open/close

if still it exists,
replace all data objects with just dummy text, if might have some faulty data.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "some white space appeared"? You get something displayed, but there is white space underneath it?

If that's the case, you could try with adding "clearfix" class to your output and adding this in your css file:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And yes, this 
 seems unecessary, that could cause the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be a encoding issue. Try to make sure you're saving your .tpl files with encode UTF-8

This should fix weird spaces.